# Debugging ajax call of cordova application with PhpStorm and XDebug

Tags: cordova, phpstorm, xdebug, gapdebug

My cordova application makes ajax calls to the backend. Sometimes I want to be able to debug the backend.

I am using PhpStorm, XDebug, GapDebug (or Chrome Inspector for Remote WebView Debugging). But I am not able to break at first line in my backend.

I have installed the XDebug helper for chrome and PhpStorm is listening for incoming php debug connections.

I guess the missing step is to set the IDE Key into my ajax calls. In the Request Header there is a Cookie value where currently I can see only the PHPSessionID. I guess there must be the value for the ide key too.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? If so, please share; thanks

Answer (score 0):

The XDebug documentation mentions that one of the ways to invoke a debug session is to include a XDEBUG_SESSION cookie in the HTTP request.  See https://xdebug.org/docs/remote.

I was able to debug my Cordova app with PhpStorm by configuring ajax to include that cookie in all requests.

```
$(document).on("deviceready", function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', 'XDEBUG_SESSION=1');
    }
  });
});
```